# How to initialize standalone Radio Button Group component checked property state with redux \ redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, radio-group

I'm learning react and I am stuck. I am trying to share a form between  Edit and Create components. I am having a really hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong to initialize the values of the checked property for the radio group. After the page loads I can toggle the radio buttons. Initially, however, neither is checked.

I'm starting to think I am setting up my checked property incorrectly on the form.

**Edit component** (forms parent component) :

```
class CompanyMasterEdit extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {this.props.fetchCompany(this.props.match.params.companyId,this.props.match.params.companyName)}

  onSubmit = (formValues) => {    this.props.editCompany(this.props.match.params.companyId, formValues)   }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Edit Company Master Record</h1>
        <h5 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span> indicates required field
        </h5>
        <CompanyMasterForm
          initialValues={_.pick(
            this.props.company,
            "isKeyCompany",...
          )}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { company: state.companies[ownProps.match.params.companyId] }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCompany, editCompany })(  CompanyMasterEdit)
```

***Form:***

```
class CompanyMasterForm extends React.Component {
    
 <form
            className="ui form error"
            onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
          >
             <Field
              label="Is This a Key Company?"
              component={RadioGroup}
              name="isKeyCompany"
              required={true}
              options={[
                { title: "Yes", value: true },
                { title: "No", value: false },
              ]}
              checked={this.props.initialValues.isKeyCompany}
              // onClick={this.setIsKeyCompany}
              //onClick={(e) => this.setState({ isKeyCompany: e.target.checked })}
              onClick={() => {this.setState((prevState) => {return {checked: !this.props.initialValues.isKeyCompany,}})
              }}
            />
            <button className="ui button primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

**RadioButtonGroup** as a separate component:

```
    class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
    
      render() {
    
      return (
          <div className={className}>
            <div className="inline fields">
              <div className={labelClassName}>
                <label>{label}</label>
              </div>
            {options.map((o) => {
            const isChecked = o.value ? "true" : "false"
            console.log("o.value :", o.value)
            return (
              <label key={o.title}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  {...input}
                  value={o.value}
                  checked={isChecked === input.value}
                />
                {o.title}
              </label>
            )
          })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    // const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    //   console.log("radio group state : ", state)
    //   return { isKeyCompany: state.form.companyMasterForm.values.isKeyCompany }
    // }
    // export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RadioGroup)
    // export default connect(null)(RadioGroup)
    export default RadioGroup
```

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/radiobuttongroup-sharedform-forked-n46de?file=/src/FormInputs/RadioGroup.js) up. I feel like I'm close and dancing all around it but I can't get it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I left an answer below. I would also recommend you study functional components. While class-based components have not been deprecated, [some of the lifecycle methods in your code have been](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle). Also, anecdotally I can tell you everything is moving towards functional components and hooks in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- Radio buttons that are mutually exclusive should have the same `name` prop. So we can just write a hardcoded string for one set of options.
- The `value` prop doesn’t determine whether the radio button is active. This is done via `checked`/`defaultChecked` instead. The `value` prop is particularly useful if we have more than two options (to label each option).
- It’s not clear what the variable `input` is doing in the last code example?
- It’s always better to avoid `"true"` and `"false"` as string values, if there are only two possible values. In this case, a boolean (`true` or `false` without the quotation marks) is more suitable. This is the simplest way to represent your state, and typos such as `"True"` won’t slip through the cracks (when you’re using strings, such typos will go unnoticed).
- If you’re using [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) (i.e. the value of an input is not kept in the component’s state), you should use `defaultChecked` instead of `checked`, if you want the user to be able to toggle the checkbox after the page has loaded.
- If you want to reuse the state of the checkbox elsewhere in your app, you’ll have to use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). In this case, setting the state should be done slightly differently as well (see below).

---

Edit: some additional remarks in response to your comment below.

(The code you provided contains syntax errors as-is, it’s easier to provide help if the code is correct and as minimal as possible (and nicely formatted). )

- You shouldn’t set your state `onSubmit` (on the form element), as you seem to be doing here. The changes should be set `onChange` (on the input element), because the state of the input element *is* the corresponding state of your app, so they must always be in sync.
- The function that actually seems to set your state is the `editCompany` reducer. So you should make it available to the `input` element, either by passing it down from a parent component (ugly) or by connecting the input component to the Redux store (cleaner).

```js
class CompanyMasterEdit extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchCompany, match } = this.props;

    fetchCompany(match.params.companyId, match.params.companyName);
  }

  render() {
    const { company } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Edit Company Master Record</h1>
        <h5 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span> indicates required field
        </h5>
        <CompanyMasterForm initialValues={_.pick(company, "isKeyCompany")} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { company: state.companies[ownProps.match.params.companyId] };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCompany, editCompany })(
  CompanyMasterEdit
);
```

```js
class CompanyMasterForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { initialValues } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className="ui form error">
        <Field
          label="Is This a Key Company?"
          component={RadioGroup}
          name="isKeyCompany"
          required={true}
          options={[
            { title: "Yes", value: true },
            { title: "No", value: false },
          ]}
          checked={initialValues.isKeyCompany}
          // onClick={this.setIsKeyCompany}
          //onClick={(e) => this.setState({ isKeyCompany: e.target.checked })}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              return { checked: !initialValues.isKeyCompany };
            });
          }}
        />
        <button className="ui button primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { company, match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <div className="inline fields">
          <div className={labelClassName}>
            {
              label /* note: not wrapped in `<label>...</label>`, because it’s not the description of one option, but rather of the entire set. */
            }
          </div>
          {options.map((o) => (
            <label key={o.title}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="isKeyCompany" // for example
                checked={company.isKeyCompany === o.value} // or passed down via props
                onChange={() =>
                  editCompany(match.params.companyId, {
                    ...company,
                    isKeyCompany: o.value,
                  })
                }
              />
              {o.title}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { company: state.companies[ownProps.match.params.companyId] };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editCompany })(RadioGroup);
```

Comment: "If you want to reuse the state of the checkbox elsewhere in your app"... this is my only goal in life right now. I thought I conveyed that in my question, but maybe not clearly. Edit component is the Forms parent.  Form component is the RBG(RadioButtonGroup) parent. My understanding was the Field component on the Form sends the RBG props. These include the onChange, onClick, or whatever other callback may need to be used. Therefore, I was trying to set all the event handlers on the Field component on the Form to pass to RBG. When RBG clicks onChange, it’s invoking the onChange passed in

Comment: I added some more comments and updated the code example (mostly the `RadioGroup` component)

Comment: Did this help you fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Bart. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain things. I’m trying to parse your explanation and implement this. At one point, I had started hooking up mapStateToProps on the Radio component, but felt I was doing things wrong. Do I need to have access to editCompany on both the radio input AND the form submission? What if other fields on the form change, don’t change the radio button, and submit? Then I need access to the editCompany reducer on the form submission also, right?

Comment: Well thanks for the help, the pointers, and the explanations @Bart. I mostly get what you are saying. Other than my last question since there are other fields on the form. But it gets me in the right direction.

Comment: As a general principle, the only components that should have access to `editCompany` are those which are concerned with changing the part of the state that `editCompany` enables you to change. Put differently, if `editCompany` allows you to edit several properties of a “company”, then every type of input (e.g. checkbox, text input, dropdown menu etc) that exists to change a company property should have access to `editCompany`. I don’t see the need to provide `editCompany` to the top-level form element, except if you want a certain state to be changed onSubmit (e.g. some “isSubmitted” property)

Comment: In efforts to keep code concise, maybe I confused the issue 1000%. Each input element calling editCompany makes sense IF the change to the state object needs to happen when the form input changes. That’s not the case. The form gets loaded with the company properties from the db. CHANGE EVERYTHING. When the form is submitted, editCompany action creator calls a reducer that calls an API endpoint to update the record in the db with new values. I don’t want to make the call to the API on every input change. I got lost when trying to update the radio button and everything went downhill from there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re writing to your database from your reducer. This is in violation of a core Redux principle: reducers must not have side effects (see https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects). Redux should concern itself with the state of your app. As such, it seems natural that the Redux state changes instantaneously when your input values change. When and whether you write the result to the database, should be an entirely separate concern.

Comment: Everything I have learned seems to be wrong or I misunderstood. In the classroom, we setup an action creator:  export const editStream = (id, formValues) => async (dispatch) => { const response = await streams.patch(`/streams/${id}`, formValues) dispatch({ type: EDIT_STREAM, payload: response.data })} That in turn dispatches the EDIT_STREAM action to the reducer: const  streamReducer =  (state = {}, action ) => {     switch(action.type){ case EDIT_STREAM:  return{...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload}. This was supposed to happen on form submission. If that is wrong then I just give up

Comment: I don't seem to be violating this: Reducer functions should only depend on their state and action arguments, and should only calculate and return a new state value based on those arguments. I am returning new state value based on values passed in. So confusing and one reason I don't understand what all the react hoopla is about. Tons of libraries with no clue what is what only brings confusion and frustration. An uphill battle in every regard and I hate it. But I honestly appreciate you taking the time to explain things. Learning basics while trying to build complex things is for the birds.

Comment: Perhaps it can be instructive to start from a working prototype, and rework it to gradually end up at your desired goal? In any case, the Redux rule (marked “essential”, not just “recommended”) seems to be in violation. You quoted part of the rule, but the very next phrase says “They must not execute any kind of asynchronous logic (...), modify variables outside the reducer”, so pretty non-negotiable if you ask me. Maybe your courseware is wrong about this? Perhaps you can find better resources online. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The value of an option is text (input.value is text but o.value is boolean). The checked property is boolean. `===` is [never going to be quite right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) unless you fix one of those things.

This change makes an option show up. Not that it's truly the right change. We probably should have a slightly more robust compare for the checked property.

```
checked={o.value == input.value}
```

It's currently boolean because you set it here

```
options={[
            { title: "Yes", value: true },
            { title: "No", value: false },
          ]}
```

Comment: Yes. I had changed that earlier. Thus the const isChecked = o.value ? "true" : "false". But not a good way to do it. Just running out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the research from @Nikki9696, but the better solution is to leave your comparison using the strict `===` check and change the options config to have string values:

```
options={[
   { title: "Yes", value: 'true' },
   { title: "No", value: 'false' },
]}
```

that's because `"true" != true` (the string value "true" is not equal to the boolean value `true`, even with type-coercion). The same can be said for a comparison between `"false"` and `false`.

Comment: Yea this got pointed out along the way. That's why I have the const isChecked = o.value ? "true" : "false". Granted, not the best solution as @Bart points out.